# Resetting position based on style.right

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I was [trying to reset animation](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/2zz0eocp/) when the image reaches right-most edge of the screen.

Everything works perfectly fine without this line:

```
if (imgObj.style.right == 0) {
    Reset();
}
```

> Is it not the right way?

```js
<!--
var imgObj = null;
var animate;

function init() {
  imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
  imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
  imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
  animate = setTimeout(moveRight, 2000); // call moveRight in 20msec
  if (imgObj.style.right == 0) {
    Reset();
  }
}

function Reset() {
  clearTimeout(animate);
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}
window.onload = init;
//-->
```

```html
<form>
  <img id="myImage" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
  <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
  <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
  <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset();" />
</form>
```

How to get the animation working along with *that above line*?

Comment: Are you willing to use jquery in your template? If so, the animation would be much easier and I can give a cross-browser working example. But including jquery only for this wouldn't be productive at all. Only if you are planning to work with it a bit more.

Comment: @Frondor I am actually learning animations. Any help is much appreciated :) jQuery, AngularJS anything

Comment: Well.. You already got a "best answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes

1. `onclick="Reset();"`  not `onclick="reset();"`
2. `parseInt(imgObj.style.left.replace("px",""))` not `parseInt(imgObj.style.left)`
3. `imgObj.style.right` is always "" you have to set some thing like `imgObj.style.left.replace("px","")>200`

```js
var imgObj = null;
var animate;

function init() {
  imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
  imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
 
  imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left.replace("px","")) + 10 + 'px';
  
  animate = setTimeout(moveRight, 2000); // call moveRight in 20msec
 
  if (parseInt(imgObj.style.left.replace("px",""))+ imgObj.width>= window.innerWidth) {
    Reset();
  }
}

function Reset(){

 clearTimeout(animate);
 imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form>
  <img id="myImage" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
  <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
  <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
  <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="Reset();return false;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to calculate window size so whenever the image reaches the right most edge, I can call reset without using `imgObj.style.right`? Since, not all window sizes will be 200px

Comment: you can change condition  to     if (parseInt(imgObj.style.left.replace("px",""))+ imgObj.width>= window.innerWidth) {
    Reset();
  }

Comment: right=parseInt(imgObj.style.left.replace("px",""))+ imgObj.width, is it work???  if it is go ahead and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!--
var imgObj = null;
var animate;

function init() {
  imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
  imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
  imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
  animate = setTimeout(moveRight, 2000); // call moveRight in 20msec
  if (imgObj.style.right == 0) {
    Reset();
  }
}

function Reset() {
  clearTimeout(animate);
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}
window.onload = init;
//-->
```

```html
<form>
  <img id="myImage" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
  <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
  <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
  <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).